# list function add() don't work but I don't know why?

Tags: java, list

This function makes a list l1 like {'a' , 'a' ,'b','b'} and if I add this list to l2 and print l2, nothing appears (I am sure that the function populates the first list (l1) because if I try to print l1 in the "if" statement it works). Any ideas?

```
public static void partition(String s, String p, String original,List<String> l1, List<List<String>> l2)
    {
        if(original.equals(p))
        {
            /*for (String all : l1) {
                System.out.println(all);
            }*/
            l2.add(l1);
        }
        String q = new String();
        a:for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
        {
            if(isPalindrome(anotherGen(s,i)) == false)
            {
                continue a;
            }
            p += anotherGen(s,i);
            l1.add(anotherGen(s,i));
            q = s.replaceFirst(anotherGen(s,i), "");
            partition(q,p,original,l1,l2);
            l1.remove(l1.size()-1);
            int t = p.lastIndexOf(anotherGen(s,i));
            p = p.substring(0,t);
        }
    }
```

Rest of the code:

```
public static String anotherGen(String s , int position)
    {
        char[] sc = s.toCharArray();
        String scc = new String();
        String[] sa = new String[s.length()];
        for(int i=0;i<sc.length;i++)
        {   
            scc += sc[i];
            sa[i] = scc;
        }
        return sa[position];
        
    }
    public static boolean isPalindrome(String s)
    {
        s = s.toLowerCase();
        boolean result = true;
        int i;
        char[] schars = s.toCharArray();
        if(s.length() == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
            for(i=0;i<s.length()/2;i++)
            {
                if(schars[i] != schars[s.length() - i - 1])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        return result;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s="aabb";
        List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<String>> l2 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        partition(s,"",s,l1,l2);
        System.out.println(l2); // print [[], [], [], []]
        }
```

Comment: So your are trying to make l2 a list of Lists? I just want to make sure that is the goal rather than copying the values of l1 into l2.

Comment: Use your IDE's debugging feature, and single-step through your program, watching the variable values.

Comment: @Buzzkillionair yes

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff ok

Comment: Do you have the code that calls this method? @MirciaGeorge

Comment: @Buzzkillionair i just add the rest of the code. The problem is that I don't know exactly how to make that list of solutions and print them.